# Can't install sqlite3 dependency with npm

Tags: node.js, linux, sqlite, npm

I'm running Pop!_OS (Ubuntu) 20.04. When I try to add sqlite3 to my dependencies on my nodejs project, I get this wall of warnings:

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> sqlite3@5.0.1 install /home/kevinlopez/Documents/Projects/wsky-be/node_modules/sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.1 and node@14.15.4 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
make: Entering directory '/home/kevinlopez/Documents/Projects/wsky-be/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/../node-addon-api/nothing.a
  COPY Release/nothing.a
  ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_action_before_build_target_unpack_sqlite_dep Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3320300/sqlite3.c
/bin/sh: 1: python: not found
make: *** [deps/action_before_build.target.mk:13: Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3320300/sqlite3.c] Error 127
make: Leaving directory '/home/kevinlopez/Documents/Projects/wsky-be/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-7630-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/kevinlopez/Documents/Projects/wsky-be/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/home/kevinlopez/Documents/Projects/wsky-be/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=6" "--node_napi_label=napi-v6"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/kevinlopez/Documents/Projects/wsky-be/node_modules/sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/kevinlopez/Documents/Projects/wsky-be/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/kevinlopez/Documents/Projects/wsky-be/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/kevinlopez/Documents/Projects/wsky-be/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-7630-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/kevinlopez/Documents/Projects/wsky-be/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/kevinlopez/Documents/Projects/wsky-be/node_modules/sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/kevinlopez/Documents/Projects/wsky-be/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/kevinlopez/Documents/Projects/wsky-be/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
npm WARN wsky-be@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN wsky-be@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.1 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@5.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@5.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kevinlopez/.npm/_logs/2021-01-17T06_26_58_042Z-debug.log
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling npm and nodejs, deleting and reinstalling node_modules and package-lock.json, deleting ~/.node-gyp and running `npm i -g node-gyp` , and installing build essentials with `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential`

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "wsky-be",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.3.1",
    "knex": "^0.21.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: python: not found` ... kind of sticks out, no?

Comment: That was it. It's trying to run the python command which doesn't exist anymore on Ubuntu 20.04. I got around this by running ```sudo apt-get install python-is-python3``` . This is only a temporary workaround, since it seems to replace any python command with the python3 command. I'll have to find something else when it needs to run a python2 command.

Comment: node-gyp is compatible with both Python 2 and 3 now, so you probably won't run into that particular issue at least with Node.

Answer (score 20):

Pass the python path to the npm install proccess, that way the python will be found

```
npm install --build-from-source --python=/usr/bin/python3
```

Remember to put the desired python version, don't forget that python3 is the best choice nowadays. I used the path: /usr/bin/python3.8 and worked as well.

found this command at: [github issue at node-sqlite3 repository](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/1328#issuecomment-629624731)

Comment: This did it for me. On Mac M1 Sonoma 14.1 python3 node 14/16, yarn install. 
yarn equivalent: npm_config_python=/usr/bin/python3 yarn install --build-from-source

Comment: still had issues on another workstation after running the above code. ended up just recloning the repo and adding python alias to .zshrc. export PATH="/usr/local/bin/python3:$PATH"
alias python=python3

Answer (score 7):

I think this issue comes from latest version of sqlite3.
Try `npm install sqlite3@4.1.1` and use it.
It works perfect for me

Comment: (current sqlite3 version = 5.0.1) ...
For me "npm install sqlite3@5.0.0" worked

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to symlinking python3 to python (which is what `python-is-python3` does) would be setting the `python` variable in your npm config. Example: `npm config set python /usr/local/bin/python3`.

Comment: This fixed my issue when trying to `npm install sqlite3` on a CircleCI build. The standard CircleCI container doesn't have `python`, only `/usr/bin/python3`.

Relevent step: `- run: npm config set python /usr/bin/python3`

Answer (score 1):

splite3 uses python 2.7 to build. Had the same problem. I had to set the path to python in the npm config. For me (on Linux) the solution was:
npm config set python /usr/bin/python2

Then I was able to install sqlite3 successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried for hours to overcome the same setback but I solved it in 2 simple steps:

1. `npm rebuild`
2. `npm i sqlite`

It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

added version  `"sqlite3": "^4.1.1"` in package.json
and ran command

```
npm install --build-from-source --python=/usr/bin/python3
```

resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

And transferring comment to answer:

I suggest you install python (make it available), given the message `/bin/sh: 1: python: not found`.

Answer (score 0):

do
`npm uninstall node-pre-gyp --save`
`npm install @mapbox/node-pre-gyp --save`
`npm install sqlite3`

the above solved my issue.

Comment: cant even do that, same error when I try to uninstall node-pre-gyp

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem. I'm working with my Office PC where everything is restricted, therefore install this sqlite3 returns error as it requires compilation during npm install. Here's what I'm figure out:

- 1. If my package.json has only `"sqlite3": "^5.0.2"` (no any other lib) then `npm install` works. But if I add all other libs that needs for my project + sqlite@5.0.2, remove nodes_modules, run `npm install` again, then it'll fail ->> solution for this is adding only `"sqlite3": "^5.0.2"` and run `npm install` first, then manually add other dependencies later and run `npm install` one more time, of course this is not a preferred way as we need to manually do
- 2. downgrage to `"sqlite3": "^4.1.1"` fixed the problem, I can define `sqlite3` with all other libs in my package.json -->> I'm going with this approach

Answer (score 0):

Edit on 2022 : Mostly its not on python but the supported version of node

Please check the supported version of Node in sqlite npm documentation and use the supported Node version (mostly by downgrading using nvm)

For me the node verion is v16.x whereas the Sqlite max supported version is v12.x, so I downgraded and the issues went off!