# npm error code 7 while installing sqlite3

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm-install, node-sqlite3, node-pre-gyp

Im trying to run a react project. I cloned the git repo and ran the command

```
npm install
```

this installed all the dependencies except sqlite3, so i tried to install sqlite3 manually by running the command

```
npm install sqlite3
```

but i get this error

```
npm ERR! code 7
npm ERR! path /home/yash/Freelance/degenbulls/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
```

this has happened in other projects as well, ive tried several things but nothing has worked for me.

I tried to install sqlite3 but i got an error with npm error code 7 and node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build command

This is the error log

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated crypto@1.0.1: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
npm WARN deprecated @walletconnect/types@1.8.0: WalletConnect's v1 SDKs are now deprecated. Please upgrade to a v2 SDK. For details see: https://docs.walletconnect.com/
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm WARN deprecated @walletconnect/mobile-registry@1.4.0: Deprecated in favor of dynamic registry available from: https://github.com/walletconnect/walletconnect-registry
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
npm WARN deprecated eip1193-provider@1.0.1: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @walletconnect/client@1.8.0: WalletConnect's v1 SDKs are now deprecated. Please upgrade to a v2 SDK. For details see: https://docs.walletconnect.com/
npm WARN deprecated @json-rpc-tools/provider@1.7.6: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm WARN deprecated @walletconnect/ethereum-provider@1.8.0: WalletConnect's v1 SDKs are now deprecated. Please upgrade to a v2 SDK. For details see: https://docs.walletconnect.com/
npm WARN deprecated @json-rpc-tools/utils@1.7.6: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm WARN deprecated @json-rpc-tools/types@1.7.6: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm WARN deprecated emailjs-com@3.2.0: The SDK name changed to @emailjs/browser
npm WARN deprecated @walletconnect/qrcode-modal@1.8.0: WalletConnect's v1 SDKs are now deprecated. Please upgrade to a v2 SDK. For details see: https://docs.walletconnect.com/
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm ERR! code 7
npm ERR! path /home/yash/Freelance/degenbulls/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
```

Comment: Is that the only output that NPM shows?

Comment: No it shows a lot of things in the terminal, but in the end I get this error

Comment: All that means is that the build process failed. _Why_ it failed is anybody's guess if you don't post the full error log.

Comment: I added the full error log

Answer (score 1):

in most cases, npm ERR! code 7 means that you have a problem in building your project, try first to build your application whether in dev or production mood, and check if you have any problem.

Comment: I didn't build this project, I talked to the builder of the project and he said it's working for him and other guys in his team too. I got this error while installing dependencies in another project recently, Maybe it's a problem with something in my pc?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while trying to install sqlite3 using node version 18
I tried switching node versions (currently on 20) and it did the trick for me

While looking for a solution for this issue I found another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68290496) that you might want to use before changing versions: `npm rebuild`